# Getting GDP info by using importXML from IMF webpage

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I'm going to get the updated GDP info by using importXML from IMF webpage.
I type in the following in the spreadsheet, but it return "N/A"
Is there anything wrong with my input?

```
=importxml("http://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/NGDP_RPCH@WEO/OEMDC/ADVEC/WEOWORLD","//*[@id='dm-main']/div[1]/radio-group/div[3]/imf-ranking/radio-group/div[2]/div[2]")
```

Answer (score 2):

The bot that fetches content for `importxml` only gets the HTML source of the page, not any dynamic elements inserted in it with JavaScript. You can see what it sees by opening the page and choosing view-source (typically available with right-click). This is the relevant HTML element:

```
<imf-ranking dataset={parent.state.dataset} indicators={parent.state.indicators} year={parent.year}></imf-ranking>
```

There is no data here. 
The attributes like `dataset={parent.state.dataset}` indicate that the data will be inserted in this element with a script. `importxml` cannot access it.